# Get my current playlist with REST API in Spotify

Tags: api, spotify

There is any way to get a user playlist via the REST API?

I search about it, but REST API is really squishy.

My idea is really simple.
I just want to get all my playlists from spotify and share that ones I want to in my website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: No.

In medium: No, but you can use the [Spotify Play Button](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/) to embed a playlist into your website instead. You need to manually make one for each playlist, but once created the embedded widget will automatically stay in sync with the playlist.

A long: If you write it yourself, yes. You'd need to write a libspotify wrapper on the server-side that exposes a REST API for your website to consume. It's not for the faint of heart, though.

Comment: What I hate about libspotify is you need to have Premium account to use it. I have Unlimited one so I can't.
I will try to use copy/paster playlist songs from spotify and making REST calls to take track data... is not what I like to do, but it will make the job. Thanks a lot!